# How to create a View template for MVC?

Tags: c#, templates, model-view-controller, dynamic-view

I have been given the task of creating a template for Views in MVC. Basically, instead of many Views (CRUD) for each entity, we would only have one that accepts generic model and displays it in Edit/Display mode.

I have so far played around with IView, WebViewPage and ViewPage, but I can't seem to get anything to work. I also searched for something like this, but can't find anything useful really.

Specifically, I don't know which C# class I could overwrite/implement to get my desired effect. Can anybody help me out here?

Answer (score -1):

When using MVC you normally have Razor Views (.cshtml).
These come in 4 flavours:

- Full Views
- Partial Views
- EditorTemplates
- DisplayTemplates

From your question, I think, you want EditorTemplates.

Create a new View in Views/Shared/EditorTemplates and name it YourGenericModel.cshtml
Inside this file write the first line:

```
@model YourGenericModel
```

You can now specify what should be rendered using the normal Razor syntax.

To Have your model displayed using your new View simply call

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.yourGenericModelInstance)
```

Comment: that is default view. I am looking for creating views for generic models. something where I could use reflection for resovling properties and then adding controls to the view dynamically and send it to the client. something like that.

Comment: Inside the YourGenericModel.cshtml you can call @Html.Editor(property, "someNameFromReflection") for each property. Use .GetType().GetProperties()... to iterate through all properties.

Comment: ok maybe I understood you wrong. what I don't understand, how can I use "model.yourGenericModelInstance" when using generics? and how would I write my @model declaration when passing a generic model which requires a <T> parameter?